# Kitchen LED ceiling light blinking

Tags: electrical, lighting

Hopefully someone can help with this issue. Everything I have researched seems to be related to a type of light I do not own. I have a kitchen LED light that has been working fine up until just recently when all of a sudden it will start to flash when turning it on. Sometimes it comes on and stays within a few seconds and sometimes it will take 10-15 minutes or more.

I attempted to take the cover off and check and see if any wiring was loose and could not locate anything causing it. None of the wires when touching or adjusting will cause it to start working again. It is not on any dimmer switch but has two different standard light switches that operate it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsMk7.jpg (Image of unit without the cover)
https://youtu.be/K_YH0blbOqY (Video of the flashing)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stumped on how to fix this.

Comment: @PaulPhillips did you read the question? No dimmer is covered.

Comment: Watching the video my guess is the driver in that fixture has failed.  (We actually have I believe the same fixture and it's a good quality fixture).  Pick up a new one (home depot I assume that's where ours came from) and replace.  99.9% that's going to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the fixture -- the driver's failed and isn't starting up properly.

Comment: Dang it. I live in period where lights have drivers, and reboot? I miss the old fashioned light bulb.

Comment: @Paulb -- the driver for a LED is relatively simple in comparison -- it converts the AC mains into the constant DC current that LEDs run on. (It's similar in role to the ballast on a fluorescent fixture.)

Comment: Thanks @ThreePhase. I was starting to that even light circuits had CPU's :)

Comment: @Paulb some do... Like my RGB undercabinet lights that actually have shows programmed for parties

Comment: @Paulb  not only do they have CPUs: they have cellular chips & send your data straight to the NSA.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft They're welcome to come down and party anytime. I Bet those NSA dudes (and dudettes) get pretty crazy in the off hours.

Answer (score -1):

Light switches go bad or get weak after so many "on/off's" or cycles.
This will cause flickering due to a poor connection.
Try replacing the switch.

Comment: I suspect your downvote is because the OP says it is flickering, not that it failed entirely.  You are free to edit your answer in any way you think might be more useful.